# Just run a single R command from rpy2 (not a source file)

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am very new to `rpy2` and I want to use it to just run a single R command. I know the `source()` function which takes a file path as the argument string, but I do not want to  write a single line to a file and call `source()` to run that line as this looks kinda indirect way to run a single line. I am wondering whether there is another function (named `run_command()` in below example) which just runs the line given as the argument.

Example: `run_command("a=3+5")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run r commands by using robjects.r from rpy2

```
from rpy2 import robjects

robjects.r('a=3+5')

#To save the output
r_result=robjects.r('a=3+5')
print(r_result[0])

8.0
```